# Sum of principal minors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there any formula for the sum of principal minors? (note: $i^{th}$ principal minor which results from omitting the $i^{th}$ row and $i^{th}$ column)

Answer (score 6):

Let us say your matrix $A$ is $N\times N$. Then you are looking at the sum of all $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ principal minors of $A$. If you can calculate the eigenvalues of $A$, then, you can find it. The $k^{th}$ symmetric function $s_k$ of eigenvalues of a given matrix is defined as the sum of all products of eigenvalues taken $k$ at a time. For example, for a $3 \times 3$ matrix,

\begin{align}s_2=\lambda_1\lambda_2+\lambda_1\lambda_3+\lambda_2\lambda_3\end{align}

Now, we have the result that
\begin{align}
s_k=\sum (all~~ k\times k ~~principal ~minors)
\end{align}
Thus you are looking at $s_{N-1}$ which can be calculated if eigenvalues are known. For a proof of this, see carl D Meyer's excellent book "Matrix Analysis".

Comment: Tnx for the comment and book, it was very helpful. 
Actually I just know that one eigenvalue is zero, hence the sum of principal minors is equal to product of the N-1 eigenvalues. Is there any way that without knowing the N-1 eigenvalues then compute the product of them?

Comment: I will think about it..